# Complete remove and reinstall R, including all packages

Tags: r, ubuntu-12.04, uninstallation

After some heavy tinkering, I must have screwed up my R installation and some package permissions. Rather than try to fix it, I just want to wipe and reinstall everything. So I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove r-base-core
sudo apt-get remove r-base
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Which did uninstall R, except when I reinstalled R, my old packages were still available (and some of them were causing troubles).

How can I do a complete reinstall, including removing all packages, except for the included base library?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In R, you can use the `.libPaths()` instruction (or `R -e '.libPaths()'` in terminal) to know where your packages are installed. Delete those folders and reinstall.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I remove two directories with my installed packages, and apt-get remove took care of the main files.

Comment: Since this is a highly upvoted question, I am asking a closely related follow up question: What If we delete any folder recursively from a specific .libPath() with an intention to remove one or more packages from a specific .libPath()?  Will it be a clean uninstallation of a package?  Case in hand same package installed twice.

Comment: i'll just add that it's _highly_ recommended to remove packages via `apt` (the package manager) if they were originally installed via the package manager; so, with the output of `.libPaths()`, check disk usage eg via `du -sch /usr/lib/R/site-library` etc etc and if there are pkgs there eg `/usr/lib/R/site-library/zoo` (however most, if not all, should be removed as dependencies when purging/autoremoving `r-base`), see what pkg they belong to via eg `dpkg -S /usr/lib/R/site-library/zoo` and then remove these pkgs eg `sudo apt purge r-cran-zoo`