# Unable to completely remove R from Ubuntu system

Tags: r, ubuntu

I have tried to remove an older version of R (3.4.4) to move to a newer one for this Ubuntu 20.04 installation. As you can see when trying to invoke R I am not getting  any installation. When I install r-base-core it notes that it is already there and then trying to call R still doesn't work.

I have tried the steps listed here: [Complete remove and reinstall R, including all packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118558/complete-remove-and-reinstall-r-including-all-packages) . I have also tried to search for R remnants and delete but so far not working. Any advice?

```
computerxx:/$ R

Command 'R' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install r-base-core

computerxx:/$ sudo apt install r-base-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
r-base-core is already the newest version (4.2.1-1.2004.0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
computerxx:/$ R

Command 'R' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install r-base-core

computerxx:/$
```

Comment: Neither `type -a R` or `which R` worked. However, `whereis R` did and returned `computerxx:/$ whereis R
R: /usr/bin/R.distrib /usr/lib/R /usr/local/lib/R /usr/share/R /usr/share/man/man1/R.1.gz
`

Comment: That is really bizarre. It used to be just `R`. It works when called. Is there a way to rename this and to get Rstudio and system to pick it up again properly?

Comment: I can call R now. There seems to be some other problems. `/usr/bin/R: line 248: /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory cannot find system Renviron`. Along with `1: package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
2: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found`. Is it best I rename back, remove this R.distrib and install again or?