# package DBI installed twice but cannot uninstall from one libpath

Tags: r, package, rstudio

So in other words, I have the package `DBI` installed twice, in two library paths (`.libpaths()[1]` and `.libpaths()[3]`). I use the Rstudio server on Ubuntu 22.

Am trying to remove the older version from `.libpaths()[3]` but am unsuccessful.

Tried the following:

1. Restarted R so the package is not loaded in the current session.
2. Ran the command: `remove.packages("DBI",lib = .libPaths()[3])`.

Repeat the above steps many times. Refreshed the package window of rstudio, and also checked using `find.package("DBI",lib.loc = .libPaths()[3])`

But the package still is installed in both libpaths.

See Rstudio screeshot.

[image]

My Rstudio version:

> RStudio 2022.07.1+554 "Spotted Wakerobin" Release
> (7872775ebddc40635780ca1ed238934c3345c5de, 2022-07-22) for Ubuntu
> Bionic Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

My Ubuntu version:

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available. 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 
LTS Release:        20.04 
Codename:       focal
```

Comment: What happens when you delete the package through the file system?  Like going to `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` and deleting the package(s).  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24118876/1082435

Comment: I havent tried that.. Wanted to avoid direct file delete in OS. But if nothing else works will use the `rm` command. Is it just one file to be removed?

Answer (score 0):

If removing the package through R's [`remove.packages()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/remove.packages.html) doesn't work, you can delete the package through the file system.  As you wrote, [`.libPaths()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html) discloses the location of each "library" (*ie*, a big directory that contain packages.

Each package is a subdirectory in the library.  Delete the package's directory to remove/uninstall the package.  It's best if no OS process is using the files within the package's directory, so close all instances of R & RStudio.

As you wrote, a package may be in multiple libraries (which is discouraged because it can cause subtle problems).  So look in each library

The library & directory structure is described in detail the 2nd edition of *R Packages*:
https://r-pkgs.org/Structure.html#sec-library.

The SO post overlaps with [Complete remove and reinstall R, including all packages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24118558/1082435).

Comment: Will try your solution soon as it needs shutting of Rstudio.